# Can you use data-vocabulary.org and schema.org on the same page?

Tags: microdata

In WordPress, can you use data-vocabulary.org and schema on the same page?

For example in a WordPress post schema.org is used to define the sidebar, page content, breadcrumbs and data-vocabulary.org for reviews stars (Rich Snippet).

The reason I am using data-vocabulary.org for reviews is because the plugin I have for this uses data-vocabulary.org for reviews rather than schema.org. And I like the plugin. I would prefer to use it in case it will not create a problem.

Using both on the same page for different things, will it be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and often you need to do this to activate widgets. Schema.org has shoddy support for things like review-aggregate and doesnt support breadcrumbs (weird eh?). Reviews especially, it fails validators until you use a mix of Schema and Data-Vocabulary. Here are some random examples:

This Schema does **not** work for Product review summary:

```
<div itemscope itemprop="aggregateRating" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="<?php echo $rating; ?>" />
    <meta itemprop="ratingCount" content="<?php echo $total_reviews; ?>" />
</div>
```

But this Data-Vocab **does** work for Product review summary:

```
<div itemscope itemprop="rating" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Rating">
    <meta itemprop="average" content="<?php echo $rating; ?>" />
    <meta itemprop="best" content="5" />
</div>
<meta itemprop="count" content="<?php echo $total_reviews; ?>" />
```

And for the actual review looping, Schema **does** work, but Data-Vocab is "depreciated":

```
<div itemscope itemprop="reviewRating" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
    <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1" />
    <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="<?php echo $review['rating']; ?>" />
    <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" />
</div>
```

Then in Breadcrumbs, Schema does **not** work, only Data-Vocab seems to fire snippets:

```
<span itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
    <?php echo $breadcrumb['separator']; ?><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="title"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></span></a>
</span>
```

I don't understand why they have not made Schema encompass all of the methodology of Data-Vocab...its strange to have to use the older methods to activate "new" Google widgets. Maybe im just crazy but thats how it seems to roll.